# How do I run VS Code on a docker container but share my local files

Tags: docker, vscode-remote

I want to run my code in a local docker container, but I want to change the code files on my operating system and not inside the container.

I want to do this because I want to:

- run git outside the container
- be able to run cypress outside the container
- be able to test my code against different images

I've tried some configurations mainly related with mounts, but I couldn't make it work.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where does the container come into it at all; can you run the code outside the container too?

Comment: The container comes in the part where I run the dev server inside it

Answer (score 1):

You should try using volumes:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Hi J-Mous, do you know how to configure that with vscode-remote? I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Hey @ArturCarvalho if I understand correctly you just need to be able to modify your code that is running inside a container from VS code on your host. That is exactly the use case of `volumes`. I dont know how exactly you start your docker stack or any other info about your setup so that depends. You should try to read and understand how `volumes` work. An example would be:

```
docker run -d \
  --name test \
  -v /your_path_on_host:/your_path_on_container \
  nginx:latest
```

This mounts the directory `/your_path_on_host` inside the container on this path `/your_path_on_container` and changing anything on your VS code from your HOST on this path should reflect the changes inside the container also on the mounted path.

Comment: I can't call it like that, that is called by the vscode-remote plugin. I think I'm close: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_adding-another-local-file-mount. But I get a bunch of errors when I try the mount. That's why I'd like to see a working one. But the error is not informative to me:

Command failed: docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=bind,source=c:\Users\ac\Documents\GitHub\a\testproj,target=/workspaces/testproj,consistency=cached --mount source=C:\Users\ac,target=~/,type=bind,consistency=cached -l vsch.quality=stable -l vsch.remote. ...